# Make spotlight open new instance of application instead of going to application

Tags: macos, spotlight

I recently moved from Windows to OSX, and find it frustrating that typing `Chrome`, `Sublime Text` or `Terminal` in Spotlight do not allow me to open a new window, but instead takes me to an open window of the application.

There's the option of running `open -n "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/"` from terminal but, that defeats the purpose of Spotlight. I'm also aware of Alfred, which is not a solution for me.

Is it possible to change the behaviour of Spotlight to suit this?

Comment: It's not really the behaviour of Spotlight you're trying to change, it's the behaviour of OS X itself. Sending 'open' to a running Mac app is always interpreted as 'bring to front'.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree - clicking on an app in the dock should not start a new instance, but rather show the running app.

Comment: I'm sure that's what I said - it will bring an already-running app to the front. Adding the -n flag is what changes the behaviour. +1s for Q & solution, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution using [flashlight](http://flashlight.nateparrott.com/), which allows you to create custom search terms for spotlight.

1. Install Flashlight
2. Enter the Flashlight app
3. Click `New Plugin` > `Run an Automator Workflow`
4. Edit contents according to needs - mine is:
   [image: Edit Flashlight plugin]
5. Click `Edit Workflow`
6. Remove notification and add `Run shell script`
7. Add command that fits needs - mine is:
   [image: Edit automator workflow]
8. Test your command works by clicking `Run` in the `Automator` window.
9. Close `Automator` and the window for the new plugin in Flashlight
10. Searching for any of the keywords in `Usage examples` input to the Flashlight plugin will allow you to run the script.

[image: Spotlight search term]

Comment: Not valid anymore since the repo has been deprecated :( It won't work with recent macOS versions